# How to use Neo4j's gds.shortestPath.dijkstra.stream for nodes with elementId(node) intead of id(node)?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a graph projected from nodes and relationships "(n1:Place)-[r:COST]->(n2:Place)".
To find the cheapest path between two nodes with names 'a' and 'z' I use [Dijkstra's shortest path algorithm](https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-data-science/current/algorithms/dijkstra-source-target/):

```
MATCH (start:Place) where 'a' = start.name
MATCH (end:Place) where 'z' = end.name
CALL gds.shortestPath.dijkstra.stream('my-graph',{
    sourceNode: id(start),
    targetNode: id(end),
    relationshipWeightProperty: 'cost'
})
YIELD nodeIds
```

It works perfectly, but I read that [id(node):int is deprecated](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/scalar/#functions-id) and in Neo4j 1.5.8 I should use the new [elementId(node):string](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/scalar/#functions-elementid) function instead.

```
MATCH (start:Place) where 'a' = start.name
MATCH (end:Place) where 'z' = end.name
CALL gds.shortestPath.dijkstra.stream('my-graph',{
    sourceNode: elementId(start),
    targetNode: elementId(end),
    relationshipWeightProperty: 'cost'
})
YIELD nodeIds
```

However, since elementId() returns a string instead of an int, it causes an exception:

```
Failed to invoke procedure `gds.shortestPath.dijkstra.stream`: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected a node or a node id for `sourceNode`. Got String.
```

Is there another option that supports pathfinding using elementId() instead of id()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also pass the whole node to the procedure. lets GDS handle the rest on how to identify the node.

Comment: I tested it and to my surprise it worked just fine, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

GDS currently does not support `elementId()` values, so you will have to use `id()`.

Answer (score 2):

elementID is a string, but you can get the id as illustrated here:

```
match (n) return  toInteger(split(elementId(n),':')[2])
```